# Mongo 3.2.20 Invalid access at address

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-3.2

My mongodb local instance just crashed on its own with the following in its log:

> Invalid access at address: 0x18
>
> Got signal: 11 (Segmentation fault).

**Environment:**

- Ubuntu 16.04
- MongoDB v3.2.20

**Backtrace:**

```
----- BEGIN BACKTRACE -----
{"backtrace":[{"b":"400000","o":"11599A2","s":"_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo"},{"b":"400000","o":"1158949"},{"b":"400000","o":"1159327"},{"b":"7FBC9AD60000","o":"11390"},{"b":"400000","o":"991E41","s":"_ZNK5mongo17IndexAccessMethod17getSpaceUsedBytesEPNS_16OperationContextE"},{"b":"400000","o":"73076E","s":"_ZN5mongo10Collection12getIndexSizeEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_14BSONObjBuilderEi"},{"b":"400000","o":"74BE4E","s":"_ZN5mongo8Database8getStatsEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_14BSONObjBuilderEd"},{"b":"400000","o":"87EF60","s":"_ZN5mongo7DBStats3runEPNS_16OperationContextERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERNS_7BSONObjEiRS8_RNS_14BSONObjBuilderE"},{"b":"400000","o":"87A686","s":"_ZN5mongo7Command3runEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_3rpc16RequestInterfaceEPNS3_21ReplyBuilderInterfaceE"},{"b":"400000","o":"87B97B","s":"_ZN5mongo7Command11execCommandEPNS_16OperationContextEPS0_RKNS_3rpc16RequestInterfaceEPNS4_21ReplyBuilderInterfaceE"},{"b":"400000","o":"786A4B","s":"_ZN5mongo11runCommandsEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_3rpc16RequestInterfaceEPNS2_21ReplyBuilderInterfaceE"},{"b":"400000","o":"9B4C8A"},{"b":"400000","o":"9B8196","s":"_ZN5mongo16assembleResponseEPNS_16OperationContextERNS_7MessageERNS_10DbResponseERKNS_11HostAndPortE"},{"b":"400000","o":"5C6F60"},{"b":"400000","o":"10FF8D1","s":"_ZN5mongo17PortMessageServer17handleIncomingMsgEPv"},{"b":"7FBC9AD60000","o":"76BA"},{"b":"7FBC9A996000","o":"10741D","s":"clone"}],"processInfo":{ "mongodbVersion" : "3.2.20", "gitVersion" : "a7a144f40b70bfe290906eb33ff2714933544af8", "compiledModules" : [], "uname" : { "sysname" : "Linux", "release" : "4.13.0-43-generic", "version" : "#48~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 17 12:56:46 UTC 2018", "machine" : "x86_64" }, "somap" : [ { "elfType" : 2, "b" : "400000", "buildId" : "907E25B81823263E277D6DC159426B098C060119" }, { "b" : "7FFEE8DE6000", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "E40F36491D2AC74EE1D4F6CBBF5D52F8D60C760C" }, { "b" : "7FBC9BCEC000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B6FD9C4DDE7FD8CF2DEE25FC19AA41607134E588" }, { "b" : "7FBC9B8A8000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "0081280CE06E36667B03C21564FECD06528E71AD" }, { "b" : "7FBC9B6A0000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "89C34D7A182387D76D5CDA1F7718F5D58824DFB3" }, { "b" : "7FBC9B49C000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "8CC8D0D119B142D839800BFF71FB71E73AEA7BD4" }, { "b" : "7FBC9B193000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "DFB85DE42DAFFD09640C8FE377D572DE3E168920" }, { "b" : "7FBC9AF7D000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "68220AE2C65D65C1B6AAA12FA6765A6EC2F5F434" }, { "b" : "7FBC9AD60000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "CE17E023542265FC11D9BC8F534BB4F070493D30" }, { "b" : "7FBC9A996000", "path" : "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "B5381A457906D279073822A5CEB24C4BFEF94DDB" }, { "b" : "7FBC9BF55000", "path" : "/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2", "elfType" : 3, "buildId" : "5D7B6259552275A3C17BD4C3FD05F5A6BF40CAA5" } ] }}
mongod(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x32) [0x15599a2]
mongod(+0x1158949) [0x1558949]
mongod(+0x1159327) [0x1559327]
libpthread.so.0(+0x11390) [0x7fbc9ad71390]
mongod(_ZNK5mongo17IndexAccessMethod17getSpaceUsedBytesEPNS_16OperationContextE+0x1) [0xd91e41]
mongod(_ZN5mongo10Collection12getIndexSizeEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_14BSONObjBuilderEi+0x8E) [0xb3076e]
mongod(_ZN5mongo8Database8getStatsEPNS_16OperationContextEPNS_14BSONObjBuilderEd+0x39E) [0xb4be4e]
mongod(_ZN5mongo7DBStats3runEPNS_16OperationContextERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEERNS_7BSONObjEiRS8_RNS_14BSONObjBuilderE+0x310) [0xc7ef60]
mongod(_ZN5mongo7Command3runEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_3rpc16RequestInterfaceEPNS3_21ReplyBuilderInterfaceE+0x676) [0xc7a686]
mongod(_ZN5mongo7Command11execCommandEPNS_16OperationContextEPS0_RKNS_3rpc16RequestInterfaceEPNS4_21ReplyBuilderInterfaceE+0x85B) [0xc7b97b]
mongod(_ZN5mongo11runCommandsEPNS_16OperationContextERKNS_3rpc16RequestInterfaceEPNS2_21ReplyBuilderInterfaceE+0x25B) [0xb86a4b]
mongod(+0x9B4C8A) [0xdb4c8a]
mongod(_ZN5mongo16assembleResponseEPNS_16OperationContextERNS_7MessageERNS_10DbResponseERKNS_11HostAndPortE+0x7D6) [0xdb8196]
mongod(+0x5C6F60) [0x9c6f60]
mongod(_ZN5mongo17PortMessageServer17handleIncomingMsgEPv+0x311) [0x14ff8d1]
libpthread.so.0(+0x76BA) [0x7fbc9ad676ba]
libc.so.6(clone+0x6D) [0x7fbc9aa9d41d]
----- END BACKTRACE -----
```

Can someone help me figure out whats the reason behind it?

Answer (score 0):

The `Segmentation fault error` is a [bug](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-31236) which has fixed in **MongoDB 3.4.6 and later**. Upgrading the instance would help.

Comment: It says "A fix for this issue is included in the 3.2.15 and 3.4.6 production releases and later."
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-29850

Comment: If the bug exists for 3.4.6 then it will definitely be reflected in the low versions, hope you are using  v3.2.20.

Comment: A [segmentation fault](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault) is a memory access error. The associated backtrace indicates the execution context when the error occurred. If you compare the backtraces this is definitely not the same issue as SERVER-31236.